# how to get the value of an php array in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

i have a PHP code that will obtain the total images of a certain website via CURL, and put it inside an PHP loop.

```
$z=1;
for ($i=0;$i<=sizeof($images_array);$i++) {
    ....<img src = "$images_array[$i]" id="$z"> ..
    $z++;
    }
```

a user can then scan through the array with a `prev`/`next` button and the current image being shown will be displayed in my `$('$current_image').val(1);`

```
$.post("curl_fetch.php?url="+ extracted_url, {
    }, function(response){
    $('#loader').html($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
    $('#current_image').val(1); // insert loop value in .val()
```

when i click a button, i want to get the value of the array, and not the loop value

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.submit', function () {
    var img = $('#current_image').val(); //get the array value, not the loop value
    alert(img);
});});
```

now, how do i properly get the array value in my `$('#current_image').val(1);` in Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing but it sounds like you want to fetch a list of images using curl and then be able to page through them one by one using jQuery. One way to do this would be to build a javascript array of the image URLs and then just update the value of the img src using that array.

```
<!-- load the page with the first image -->
<img src="<?php echo $images_array[0]; ?>" id="visible_img"></img>
<button id="previous"><< previous</button>
<button id="next">next >></button>

<!-- setup a javascript array of images and listen for clicks -->
<script type="text/javascript">
        var curIdx = 0;
        var imageUrls = ["<?php echo implode('","', $images_array); ?>"];

        // display the previous image (if there is one)
        $("#previous").click(function() { 
                if (curIdx > 0) {
                        curIdx--;
                        $("#visible_img").attr("src", imageUrls[curIdx]);     
                }
        });     

        // display the next image (if there is one)
        $("#next").click(function() {
                if (curIdx < imageUrls.length - 1) { 
                        curIdx++;
                        $("#visible_img").attr("src", imageUrls[curIdx]);     
                }
        });     
</script>
```